# 3D plots with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I am trying to plot 3D plots with `pgfplots`. I have started with an example from documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% \usepackage{3dplot}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
% this yields a 3x4 matrix:
\addplot3+[mesh] coordinates {
(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0)
(0,1,0) (1,1,0.6) (2,1,0.7) (3,1,0.5)
(0,2,0) (1,2,0.7) (2,2,0.8) (3,2,0.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

When I look into the file .log I can read:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/mesh' and I am going to ignore it.
>   Perhaps you misspelled it.

I have re-installed pgfplots package and the result is the same.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I removed the thanks and sign-off at the end. This is just the style here, to keep questions and answers clean. Thanks is best expressed by upvoting answers that help you. In addition, I have indented the block of code with four spaces, which the presents the result with syntax highlighting. With the quote I put angle brackets beside the lines. These are available as buttons in the editor too. To see what I did, hit `edit` and take a look.

Comment: Can you place a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/9043) in the code block please? When I added the appropriate minimal code around what you have here it compiled fine.

Comment: Your code works fine on my computer. Can you also include the document preamble?

Comment: Make sure that you have the current version (1.5.1) of [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots). You will need at least version 1.4.1 of this package.

Comment: Here is the document preambule I use :\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


% \usepackage{3dplot}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]

  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
% this yields a 3x4 matrix:
\addplot3+[mesh] coordinates {
(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0)
(0,1,0) (1,1,0.6) (2,1,0.7) (3,1,0.5)
(0,2,0) (1,2,0.7) (2,2,0.8) (3,2,0.5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Comment: Your code still compiles fine for me. What version of TeX are you on, and on which OS? What version of pgfplots are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am currently using kubuntu 10.04 as OS, TeX version 3.141592 and pgfplot v 1.5.1.

Comment: what version of `pgf` are you on? I am guessing `2.00`, you should install `2.10`.

Answer (score 3):

The example works well with the new version of `pgfplots` and `tikz`.

[The newest version of tikz is available at sourceforge:](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=cvs&group_id=142562)